# Lifetime of closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

Can someone shed light on the Lifetime of a closure? How to kill/destroy it? Any way to list all closures? I googled a lot but couldn't find anything related, any related links atleast will be helpful.

Example:

```
var inc = function() {
    var x = 0; // creating a closure
    return function(){
        return x++;
    }
}
alert(inc());
```

Is the closure killed when the `alert(inc())` function call returns?

Comment: kill/destroy? let it go out of context and/or allow all references to it to lapse.

Comment: A closure is simply a function instance together with an environment. Technically speaking, every function is a closure in JavaScript.

Comment: So, you are basically asking how long functions exist, how you can "destroy" them and how you can list all defined functions.

Comment: *"Is it like the moment function containing inc returns/ends, closure is killed?"* In this case yes, because you don't keep a reference to the return value. However, if you assign it to a variable, `var func = inc();`, then the function will exist until `func` goes out of scope or you are assigning a different value to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closure is part of a function instance.
The garbage collector will collect it as it collects the function.

There is no way to list them.

Answer (score 3):

Closures last until the garbage collector picks them up. This usually happens when there are no more references pointing to it (if it doesn't, then it's a memory leak). You can't manually destroy them, but if you know what is referencing it you could `delete referenceVariable` and it should trigger the GC.

As far as I am aware there is no way to get a list of closures.